# On reaching the end of the scrollview using SingleChildScrollView - listener called twice

Tags: flutter, scroll

I am using SingleChildScrollView and a scrollController to be notified when reaching the end of the scroll view

**the SingleChildScrollView component:**

```
 Expanded(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
      controller: controller.scrollController,
      physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
      child: Center(
          child: Obx(() =>
              controller.busy && controller.itemList.isEmpty
                  ? loader
                  : Column(children: [
                      listWidget(controller.itemList),
                      if (controller.busy) loader
                    ]))),
```

**the Listener:**

```
      scrollController.addListener(() {
          if (scrollController.offset >=
                  scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent &&
              !scrollController.position.outOfRange) {
              _next();
            
}
```

but for some reason it is calling *`_next()`*  twice when I am reaching the end of the scroll view and not once as it should.
any idea why? am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
physics: ClampingScrollPhysics()
```

in place of

```
physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
```

which will clamp the scroll when it reaches the end and will not bounce. The bounce will make the method call twice